# how to iterate a list without using JSTL in JSP?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, controller

I face an error below when I try to iterate a list from a controller without using JSTL in spring boot.

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Tue Dec 20 16:03:05 IST 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> bean allShoes not found within scope
> java.lang.InstantiationException: bean allShoes not found within scope

**my JSP code is:**

```
    <jsp:useBean id="allShoes" type="java.util.List" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
    
<%
        for(Iterator it = allShoes.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            ShoeData shoe = (ShoeData) it.next();
    %>
    
    <%= shoe.getId() %>
    <%= shoe.getColor() %>
    
    <%} %>
```

**my Controller code is:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getallitem", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllItem() {
        List<ShoeData> allShoes = resource.getAllShoes();
        return "warehouse";
    }
```

how can i solve this issue without using JSTL?

Comment: it will return "warehouse" will take to the JSP page in the name of warehouse.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not JSTL problems, your error message is `bean allShoes not found within scope`

your controller just create a object `allShoes`, but does not pass it to anywhere or store it in somewhere. your jsp can not get bean `allShoes`.

try this , I am test ok, in Spring Boot 2.x
I use `List<ShoeData> allShoes=new ArrayList<ShoeData>();` and `allShoes.add(new ShoeData("101","Red"));` for temp test data.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getallitem", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllItem(Map<String, Object> model) {
        //List<ShoeData> allShoes = resource.getAllShoes();
        List<ShoeData> allShoes=new ArrayList<ShoeData>();
        allShoes.add(new ShoeData("101","Red"));
        allShoes.add(new ShoeData("102","Blue"));
        allShoes.add(new ShoeData("103","Black"));
        model.put("allShoes", allShoes);
        return "warehouse";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added the Model Interface and was able to receive the data in JSP. Your explanation was helpful!!!